Typescript & RabbitMQ: noAck flag does not work
I'm modeling a microservice system with fixed size queues: after reaching the fixed size messages are discarded. I expect RabbitMQ to remove messages only after they have been acked, but they are deleted anyway whether they are acked or not.
To do that, I am using RabbitMQ with typescript. Below the policy of one of the queues (with fixed size 50)
{
"name": "parser_queue_length_limit",
"vhost": "pipeline-vhost",
"pattern": "^parser.queue$",
"apply-to": "queues",
"definition": {
"max-length": 50,
"overflow": "reject-publish"
}
},
The problem arises when I consume messages: without any ack I expect sooner or later the queue to reach the maximum size and all messages will be discarded (this happens if I don't set up any consumers for the queue), but this does not happen.
RabbitMQConnection.getChannel().then((channel: Channel) => {
    channel.consume(queueName, async (msg: ConsumeMessage | null) => {
        if (msg !== null) {
            const taskData: TaskType = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
            processTask(taskData);
        }
    });
});

I tried to explicitly use noAck: false to ensure the above behaviour, but nothing changes.
